# suoders.d/ not working on ubuntu server 16 to 22.04

Tags: server, permissions, sudo

Long story short, I'm trying to enable NOPASSWD for some user by creataing a file called `user` inside `/etc/sudoers.d/` folder.

The file has the right permissions `0440` and the content seems alright `user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

When I run `visudo -c` to check whether or not everything is alright, it doesn't even print the files inside `suoders.d`.

It always says :

```
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/README: parsed OK
```

Even tho i don't have any `README` file inside this folder...

I have this issue on 4 VMs running Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04.
I tried on my "Desktop" version and it seems that I canno't replicate this issue, i'm really going crazy.

If you have any idea...

Thanks !

Comment: The default name is `/etc/**sudo**ers.d/` not `/etc/**suod**ers.d/` - please check your spelling - including that of the `@includedir` directives in your `/etc/sudoers` file(s)

Comment: It was a typo from my end. Also, the directive is `#includedir` not `@includedir` if it makes any difference.

Comment: `#includedir` is the older notation (pre-1.9.1) but is supported for backward compatibility

Comment: I don't really know what's the issue. I tried to run `visudo -cf /etc/sudoers.d/user` and it does print that the parsing is right. But running it with only `-c` doesn't show any file inside the `suoders.d` folder. I tried to add the line directly to the `/etc/suoders` file and it is working but this is not really what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: Is the file name literally `user`? or is it something else?

Comment: this is something else, "ansible" to be more precise. I tried to add another but it keeps returning the same output with the "README" that shouldn't be displayed if i'm not mistaken ?